# Assigning values to the an array after using Compare-Object

Tags: arrays, powershell, compareobject

I have been trying to assign values of Compare-Object results but i am getting additional informations on the output.

Here is the code:

```
$a = (dir C:\_pc\*).BaseName
$b = (dir C:\Users\username\Documents\folder\Jezyki\*).BaseName
$c = (Compare-Object -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent $a $b)
foreach ($element in $c) {
"$element"
}
Write-Output ($c)
```

Example output of runing this script:

```
@{InputObject=FolderName; SideIndicator===}
```

Comment: For me, its unclear what you are asking. What do you wan't to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to get values from Compare-Object -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent $a $b and assign them to an array called $c.

Comment: Maybe you want something like `$c = (Compare-Object -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent $a $b) | select -expand InputObject`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `-PassThru` switch for `Compare-Object`. It will output the strings. If the object was an object, it would append sideindicator as an extra property.

Ex.

```
$c = Compare-Object -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent $a $b -PassThru
```

Also, if you would like to keep the original `FileInfo`-object, you could specify `-Property Basename` to compare that value only without throwing away the rest of the object. Ex.

```
$c = Compare-Object (dir C:\_pc\*) (dir C:\Users\username\Documents\folder\Jezyki\*) -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent -Property Basename -PassThru
```